# How to bind a control's property to a property of the control's element?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I need a digit control to my windows phone app.

I try to create a custom control but I can't bind a property of the control to the control's element.

I had added a dependency property to the control

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty LineThicknessProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("LineThickness", typeof (double), typeof (DigitControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(double)));

[DefaultValue(10D)]
public double LineThickness
{
    get { return (double) GetValue(LineThicknessProperty); }
    set { SetValue(LineThicknessProperty, value); }
}
```

And have tried to bind it to the control's element

```
<UserControl x:Class="Library.DigitControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    d:DesignHeight="480" d:DesignWidth="480">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Rectangle Margin="0" StrokeThickness="0" Width="{Binding LineThickness, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Fill="#FFFF5454" RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

But it doesn't work. Is where a way to bind that property to the element's property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in the code behind.

Set a name:

```
<Rectangle x:Name="theRect" Margin="0" StrokeThickness="0" Fill="#FFFF5454" RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5"/>
```

Then in code behind:

```
theRect.SetBinding(Rectangle.WidthProperty, new Binding("LineThickness"){Source = this});
```

Not at PC with Visual Studio, so applogies if it's not 100% compileable! But gives you the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

What you have done wont work because `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}` sets the source to  the target object, which is the Rectangle in your case.

And since rectangle doesn't have a LineThickness property, the binding fails.

To get the right binding you can do several things.

The preferable approach would probably be to set `this.DataContext = this;` in your UserControl contructor, and then simply set the binding as `Width="{Binding LineThickness}"` in your XAML.

Or you could target the closest element of type UserControl and find the property on that one, if you don't feel like setting the Datacontext:

```
Width="{Binding LineThickness, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"
```

**Update**
You can also simply give the UserControl a name, and reference it with the ElementName property in the binding:

```
<UserControl x:Name="uc1" ... </UserControl>

Width="{Binding LineThickness, ElementName=uc1}"
```

Comment: Unfortunatly I couldn't use the FindAncestor it's dosn't supported by the windows phone.

Comment: Ok, but you can use the DataContext solution then?

Comment: No it can solve the current issue but will born a lot of new one